# What is 502 Proxy error? How to Resolve it

Tags: apache, tomcat, artifactory

When i try to login into Artifactory web appliaction ,its showing proxy error. The Error message is below.

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /artifactory/webapp/login.html.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at XX.XX.XX.XX Port 80
```

Any Solution for this?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Artifactory log? how is your proxy configured? can you login Artifactory directly (bypassing the proxy)?

Comment: In error log also same error...connection time out..and  proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by .............

Comment: This looks like an error from an Apache log not Artifactory. I guess you have an Apache HTTPd server in front of Artifactory serving as a proxy.

Comment: Yes Drorb..I increased the timeout to 120 sec in httpd.conf . Now i m  able to login. But the Artifactory appliaction is taking more than 100 sec to login...Is there any way to reduce this time.

Comment: This is not normal, should be much faster. I would start by making sure it has enough memory to run - http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/System+Requirements

Comment: /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -Djava                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseG1GC -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Dartifactory.home=/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -Djava.

Comment: I think we are update to date......:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75361/discussion-between-drorb-and-anil-yadav).

Comment: I have similar issue, it was not a proxy issue but a docker container which didn't restart properly. docker compose down, then … up solve in my case.